# Video not centered, JS causing it?

Tags: javascript, video, flipclock

If you look at this page: http://www.groenesmoothiehandboek.nl/sp/ you will see that the video is slightly offcenter.

You will also see there is a counter (flipclock.js) above. To call the counter  we use this code:

```
<div style="width:100%; background:url(img/bg-countdown.png) center top no-repeat; height:140px; margin:0 auto; z-index:9999;">
```

If i delete this part, the video centers perfectly.

I am already trying to fix this little bug for over an hour without success.

Does anyone know how i can maybe fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect the scroll bar on the right of the page.

Comment: It's specifically the "height" attribute on the div that you've provided the code for. In Chrome's element inspector, disabling that one attribute fixes the video, but causes about 45 pixels of whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap this div:

```
<!-- notice no height attribute here -->
<div style="width:100%; background:url(img/bg-countdown.png) center top no-repeat; margin:0 auto; z-index:9999;">
  <!-- stuff from inside this div -->
</div>
```

inside of this div:

```
<div style="height: 140px;">
  <!-- Place the entire div from above here -->
</div>
```

Your problem is fixed.

Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6RcJ.png

Answer (score 0):

I think ive fixed this one for you:

Add `float: left` to the wrapper of the counter. (the one with these properties

```
{ 
width: 100%;
background: url(img/bg-countdown.png) center top no-repeat;
height: 140px;
margin: 0 auto;
z-index: 9999;

}
```

Add these to the div underneath it

```
width: 100%; 
float:left;
```

(the div with these properties):

```
background:url(img/bg-vid.jpg) center top no-repeat; 
height:878px;
max-width:1920px;
margin:0 auto;
```

should be fixed. I strongly suggest you work with classes and id's to add CSS :). It's more readable that way. Good Luck with the smoothies ;)